# How to pre-computing mp3 file on Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, oboe

I have to make a visualizer app. I'm doing this using AudioPlayer and AudioManager class and drawing the miusic wave using canvas. But the problem is that I have to play the music! I need to draw the music waves and save them as pngs in sd card without playing the music. I'm thinking about Oboe library but I can not find any think to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oboe won't help you with this as it's just for *playing* audio. What you need to do is

- Extract/decode the MP3 into PCM.
- Convert the PCM values into an image.

Here's some ideas:

- You could use [audiowaveform](https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform)
- For just doing the MP3 extraction you could use the Oboe RhythmGame sample code [here](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/samples/RhythmGame/src/main/cpp/Game.cpp#L206)